# How do you keep inherited properties from one class after polymorphing to an interface object?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

(Update: It's been brought to my attention that the Quit method doesn't need to take parameters and I was over-complicating it by assuming it had to.  I'm going to adjust it now and see if it works.)

I have 2 classes, Employee and Person, and an interface called iQuittable.  Employee inherits from Person, the properties of FirstName and LastName.

I'm supposed to use polymorphism to create an object of the interface, IQuittable and call the Quit method on it. Since Employee also inherits from IQuittable, I tried morphing Employee into an IQuittable object. The problem is that once it morphs, it no longer has access to the Person properties.  The Quit method involves FirstName and LastName from Person, so I tried putting those properties into the interface file and quickly realized it wasn't possible.

How can I morph Employee into IQuittable and still retain the properties from Person?

Note: I changed the parameters of the Quit method to take iQuittable parameters instead of Employee, since I used polymorphism on Employee.  Is that wrong?  There are places where "employee" is still intact because I tried changing it and it still gave me errors and I was unsure if it should be changed.

I'd greatly appreciate if anyone could take a look at my code below and tell me what should be adjusted so that Quit can be called on an iQuittable object and still have the FirstName and LastName properties.

```
**Program file:**

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace interfaces
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IQuittable NewEmployee = new Employee();

            NewEmployee.FirstName = "Kitty";
            NewEmployee.LastName = "Katz";

            NewEmployee.Quit(NewEmployee);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

**Person file:**

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace interfaces

{
    public abstract class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}

**Employee file:**

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace interfaces
{
    class Employee : Person, IQuittable
    {     
        public void Quit(IQuittable Quitter)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Employee.FirstName + " " + Employee.LastName + " has quit.");
        }
    }
}

**Interface file:**

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace interfaces
{
    interface IQuittable
    {
         void Quit(IQuittable Quitter);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by the example code. To clarify, an will the IQuittable passed into Quit always be itself? In that case, IQuittable.Quit doesn't need to take any parameters. You can just use this.FirstName, etc.

Comment: that makes sense, I don't know why I thought it had to have a parameter to begin with.. but you're right!  I'll try changing it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IQuittable NewEmployee = new Employee();

        ((Employee)NewEmployee).FirstName = "Kitty";
        ((Employee)NewEmployee).LastName = "Katz";

        NewEmployee.Quit(NewEmployee);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

interface IQuittable
{
    void Quit(IQuittable Quitter);
}

public abstract class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Employee : Person, IQuittable
{
    public void Quit(IQuittable Quitter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName + " has quit.");
    }
}
```